# How to create an Ubuntu 12.10 live CD?

Tags: 12.10, live-cd

I downloaded the Ubuntu 12.10 installer from Ubuntu website. However, I find that it is not an iso image and I am unable to create a live CD (or DVD) from it. I could not find any help from Ubuntu website as well as internet. Please help.

PS - My OS is Windows XP. The Ubuntu installer I downloaded from Ubuntu website is a zip file. I unzipped the file and it has a wubi file.

PS - Thanks. I could create a Live CD. 1) First I tried to do it in my laptop which has Win 7. It was showing the Ubuntu installer as a zip file and could not able to burn it in to a DVD. At that time I raised the question. 2) Later I copied the installer in my desktop which has Win XP. There the installer is shown as an ISO file and I burnt it in to a DVD and created the Live CD. This is working nicely in the the desktop. 3) I tried to run the Live Cd in my Laptop which is an AMD machine, the system does not boot up. 4) In my office desktop which has Win 7 the Ubuntu installer is showing as an ISO file. My questions are as follows: A) Why the Ubuntu installer file is showing differently in different machines? B) Why the Live CD is not working in my Laptop?

Comment: This is probably happening because you have an archive utility (maybe WinZIP?) configured to open ISO images. (This will happen for most such utilities, if you configure them to open *all* archive file types ...even though an ISO is not an archive in the strictest sense.) This will make it look just like an archive file (like a ZIP) file, and if Windows Explorer is configured to "hide extensions for known file types" then you won't see the `.iso` at the end of the file. My answer to [this similar question](http://askubuntu.com/q/249743/22949) should apply equally to your situation.

Answer (score 0):

It has to be a ISO file if it's not a **wubi** installer or something I don't know what system you are using now but if you are using **Windows** download and install [this](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/) if you are using **Linux** download and install UNetbootin sudo `apt-get install unetbootin` (if you want to make a live USB).

Or just download normal **ISO** from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) again and burn it with **Brasero Disc Burner** for Linux or any program on windows it's already in default in there I think.

I don't really know what the problem is you cant download anything different from Ubuntu site than a ISO disc image...

Edit: Or you could have downloaded a .torrent file if you did install any torrent program so you can download the ISO file even quicker.

---

Edit:
Ok I will answer your questions... **AMD** is a 64x bit processor so you have to download [this](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=64&distro=desktop&status=zeroc) file and just make a live CD it's not a zip or something it's normal ISO. You downloaded a 32x bit version of Ubuntu that’s why.

I don't know maybe a broken ISO or something or broken download who knows.

Answer (score 0):

I think the 32 bit version conflict mentioned by Da1T is probably right. As for the zip file problem, you may have had your file extension settings messed up (i.e. your default program for ISOs was windows explorer or 7zip or something) When you view the file properties, what does it say for the extension? If you rename it to .iso instead of .zip, does it work?