# What to do with an Ubuntu disk image that appears as a WinRAR file?

Tags: installation, windows, iso, disk-image

I've never used Ubuntu before. Just heard from some friends. "IT'S GREAT!!!", they used to say. So i decided to try it. I downloaded WUBI, and ran it but 'twas takin' too much time. So I decided to download the .ISO Image file separately. It couldn't download more after 150 mB, and got interrupted (and cancelled) itself. I just went to [Ubuntu's Website](http://www.ubuntu.com/), and further went to [Ask Ubuntu](http://www.askubuntu.com/), and searched for my question. After having found a related one, which told

> "***try the torrent way***"

So I downloaded it through the torrent. And after that when I opened the .rar file, there wasn't any .ISO image file; just some folders with names like .disc, boot, ISOLINUX, etc. I searched for the .ISO file but nothin' there: ANYONE HELP ME, PLEASE!!! or this will drive me into never thinkin' about Ubuntu again.

Comment: Did you choose to save the file or to open it?

Comment: The torrent shouldn't be a .rar file with no .iso image, why did you download the torrent from?

Comment: If you have a slow connection, you might want to consider this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD

Comment: But do read up on it otherwise you'll have no joy. "To install, boot your computer from the the Minimal CD and type 'cli' (command line install) at the prompt. You can then follow the instructions from the text-based installer. After the base system is installed, log in, and type 'sudo tasksel' to select the system to install."

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/249750/how-do-i-download-ubuntu-using-bittorrent-on-windows. I just created that question, I considered editing this one into that text, but I didn't because I thought it was too major an edit.

Comment: @Zunnoor Since you already have the `iso` image downloaded and you prefer to install Ubuntu within Windows (ie; Wubi installation) - look at this question - [Can Wubi use the ISO I already have?](http://askubuntu.com/q/243143/114818).

Comment: @Aditya: should I have edited this question into that one instead? Or should I have created that question without flagging this one?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The file probably did not actually have a `.rar` extension. It probably showed *no* extension, and when you double-clicked it, it opened in WinRAR. That looks like this:

[image: Windows Explorer, showing an Ubuntu ISO image as a WinRAR file, even though it is not a .rar file.]

And when you opened it, it probably looked something like this (the files inside may have been different, though, as it appears you downloaded the alternate CD):

[image: WinRAR, having opened an Ubuntu ISO image.]

#### This happens when these two conditions both hold:

1. Windows is configured to *Hide extensions for known file types*, which is the case by default.

   [image: Folder Options in Windows 7, showing the "Hide extensions for known file types" option]

   <sup>***It's not necessary to change this setting**, but if you want to do so, **Folder Options** is in **Control Panel** (in Windows Vista and later, it's in the **Appearance and Personalization** category).*</sup>
2. WinRAR is installed, and configured to open ISO images.

   [image: File associations in WinRAR setup.]

   <sup>***It's not necessary to change this either**, but if you want to after installing WinRAR, open WinRAR and go to **Options** > **Settings...** and click the **Integration** tab. You can adust file associations there. You can also adjust them in the **Default Programs** applet in the **Control Panel** (it's in the **Programs** category).*</sup>

This is unrelated to *how* you obtained the ISO image. The problem is that you're opening the ISO image as an archive. You don't have to use WinRAR on the ISO image. Instead...

#### If you want to install Ubuntu alongside Windows (*or* replace Windows with Ubuntu):

Burn the ISO image to a CD/DVD or write it to a USB flash drive, then boot from that. See:

- [How to burn a DVD on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/burn-a-dvd-on-windows)
- [How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows)
- [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

#### If you want to install Ubuntu inside Windows using Wubi:

You can install [a Wubi system](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows) from a pre-downloaded ISO image by [downloading `wubi.exe`](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/windows-installer) from the Ubuntu website (this is a very small file), then make an empty folder, and put `wubi.exe` and your ISO image (which, as explained above, may not show any file extension) in that folder. Then run `wubi.exe`. Make sure `wubi.exe` and the ISO image file are for the *same version number* of Ubuntu.

- However, you need the desktop CD/DVD image for this. You seem to have downloaded the alternate CD, which is not suitable for this purpose.
- And for readers wishing to install Ubuntu *via Wubi* on computers that shipped with Windows 8 preinstalled: [at least currently that is not supported and will not work](https://askubuntu.com/a/225082/22949). (But [you can still create a regular (non-Wubi) Ubuntu installation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported).)

*As a related but somewhat different situation, sometimes users confuse an ISO image and the program that opens it. See [Ubuntu image download either downloaded or opened Roxio instead. Why?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/267415/ubuntu-image-download-either-downloaded-or-opened-roxio-instead-why) (In contrast, here the confusion is between an ISO image and another file type opened by the program set to open ISOs.)*

Comment: Go Eliah, kudos for having way way way more patience than me with windows users.

Comment: @Eliah Kagan: This seems to be the solution (I haven't tried it yet, though. But '_How do you change those "preferences"?_'

Comment: @ZunnoorAwan I've added information about how to change these settings, but *you don't have to.* (The instructions for creating a CD/DVD or USB flash drive of Ubuntu and installing work just as well either way.)

Answer (score 1):

The Ubuntu torrent releases are not rar'd for any reason and are distributed as ISO's. If you have downloaded from an unverified source it would not be recommended to install that version.
http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads

Comment: I downloaded it from the Alternative Downloads section from the 12.10 installation section. I went to <a herf="http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads">Ubuntu.com/download/desktop/alternative-downloads</a> and chose the "ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso.torrent". Verified now?

Comment: The release named ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso has a hash of 335990D615594B9BE409CCFEB95864E24EC702C7 and contains only 1 file, ubuntu-12.10-desktop-i386.iso