# Where can I get the iso file needed for installing UUI?

Tags: iso

To install the Universal USB Installer (UUI) I need to have an **iso file**. Where can I get it (from)?

Comment: @Rinzwind Canonical officially recommends using the Universal USB Installer to produce installation media (in [these instructions](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows), one click away from the link you just posted). So I'd suggest questions about the Universal USB Installer are not off-topic. But let's close this as a duplicate of [How do I install Ubuntu?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu) By the way, by default Windows doesn't show file extensions, so [people get confused](http://askubuntu.com/q/249743/22949) about the install ISO.

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on what you want to do with UUI. I assume you are are planning to use it to create a bootable USB stick for Ubuntu installation. In this case, there's a guide at http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows with step-by-step instructions.

On the same page (and on any other subpage of ubuntu.com) you'll find a big download button in the orange menu-bar at the top. Download the DVD image of the Ubuntu version you'd like.

A .iso file is a premastered CD or DVD disk image (more precisely, it's a file containing an ISO 9600 filesystem). These can either be burnt to an optical medium using any CD/DVD writing software, or read directly to access the contained files (you can think of it as being similar to unzipping a .zip file, although it's technically different). UUI extracts the files within the .iso to a USB drive and then installs a bootloader on the USB drive, in order to allow you to boot from it.