# I need specific help installing ubuntu onto my computer

Tags: system-installation

I'm following a tutorial on how to install ubuntu onto my computer. I want to replace Windows completely. The tutorial says: "Step 2: Locate the .iso file and burn it to your disk" ... GREAT. There's hundreds or thousands of files in the download and I can't find ANY of them that are a .iso file so I don't know what to put onto the disk. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can downlad it from https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop There are How-To documents there, too. In general, don't report "I am following a tutorial", instead show us what you typed, and what the system said/did in response. If I had a dollar for every time the tutorial said "X" and I typed "Y", ....

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

Comment: You almost certainly downloaded just one file. That file is the .iso file. In Windows, you may not see the .iso extension, even though that is part of the filename. From your description, it sounds like you've opened up the .iso file and are browsing its contents. You should instead write the .iso itself to a USB flash drive or burn it to a DVD, as the instructions describe. See [What to do with an Ubuntu disk image that appears as a WinRAR file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249743/what-to-do-with-an-ubuntu-disk-image-that-appears-as-a-winrar-file)

Comment: @TejasLotlikar "How do I install Ubuntu?" is also a good link for this question. Someone should vote for that one too.

Comment: You download one iso file. It can be shown as an archive in Windows that is wrong. You need to burn the iso file you downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry. I figured out what I was doing wrong.

1) I didn't understand that the entire folder was to be treated as one file.

2) I wasn't burning the iso file to the disk properly, I didn't realize that I needed to download a program so that I could burn to the disk as an image.

3) Once I got the disk made properly, everything went smoothly from there. Sorry for wasting everyone's time, please disregard this question. Thank you to everyone who responded.

Comment: It is not "the entire folder", it really is one file, but Windows may be showing it as a folder.

Answer (score 2):

How to create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0

How to create a bootable USB stick on Windows

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-windows#0

How to create a bootable USB stuck on Mac OS

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0

How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#0

How to burn a DVD on Windows

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-windows#0

Myself, I'd suggest just using a search engine (eg. https://eu.startpage.com/) and searching with a `site:*.ubuntu.com` so the results are limited to official sites.. *What I listed are just some from the first page of such a search*

Comment: Standard Ubuntu wiki/help/tutorial pages may not be the easiest to use, esp. wiki pages can be dated, but they've been vetted at least in some way, provide the date of last editor/edit & can be tracked to who did what & why (in most cases anyway; look bottom right in wiki/help).  A 3rd party source may be trustworthy, it may not - it's on you to verify. This is why I stick to official sources generally.