# Where is the ISO file?

Tags: iso

I have recently downloaded Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS from  http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop,but instead of .iso file it gave me a zip.

Where can I find the .iso file?

[image: screenshot of an Ubuntu ISO file open in WinRAR in Windows]

Comment: Why do you think you are not looking into the ISO?  The window title says the name.

Comment: Your posted image clearly shows that you have an .iso file. Look at the filename. I'm not sure why you *opened* the .iso file in Windows, but the result that you show seems like expected behavior (WinRAR can open .iso format)

Comment: To create a bootable DVD it is asking for ans iso image.I cannot find it in the downloaded file!

Comment: The .iso image IS the (entire) downloaded file. That is why it has an .iso suffix. Stop looking *inside* the .iso file for some other, smaller .iso file.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What to do with an Ubuntu disk image that appears as a WinRAR file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249743/what-to-do-with-an-ubuntu-disk-image-that-appears-as-a-winrar-file) Both here and htere, the application opening the .iso file is WinRAR. Windows Explorer is showing .iso images with an confusing icon. Combined with its default behavior of hiding extensions (like the ".iso" suffix) for known file types, that creates this situation. For some reason this confusion seems to arise mostly with WinRAR, though it could happen with other programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .zip file you have is, in fact, the iso. When you open the iso in Windows, it comes up as a .zip folder, but it has .iso in the name. Use the .zip as the iso file.

Comment: So I have to burn the zip on the DVD?

Comment: From what I can tell. Though, from my experience, it's much easier to use a usb drive instead, and use a program like Rufus. All I know is that you did, in fact, download the iso image.

Comment: Thank you very much!:)

Comment: No problem. Also, remember to accept answers that answer your question.